# View outlet not set with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

I have a NIB that contains a `UINavigationController` which has a `UIViewController`. The `UIViewController` is being loaded externally from another nib. I am unable to set the view property thus I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "LBRootViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

How can I set my view property correctly?

Comment: Why are you asking this question multiple times?

Comment: maybe the answers given in other questions are not working or incomplete or not clear...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a nib file of `LBRootViewController.xib`. Inside that nib is a view controller subclass that has an outlet named `view`. That outlet is not set.

When your (default name) `MainWindow.xib` loads, it instantiates an instance of `LBRootViewController` but then finds that the controller has no view outlet meaning it cannot display anything.

The nib you need to examine is `LBRootViewController.xib` and not `MainWindow.xib`.

If for some reason the `LBRootViewController` object in `LBRootViewController.xib` doesn't have a view property, then you have set the object to the wrong class i.e. something other than a UIViewController subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not assign a 'view' property for the 'File's Owner' at the Interface Builder. (if file's owner is UIViewController)

Comment: I think you can change a view when its needed. Try to assign any view in IB.

Comment: i can assign a view, but i am loading from an external nib, so a view wont suffice in my case